# print an excel file in the client machine

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have an excel file located in the server. 
I need to allow the user to print the excel file from a web application. The printing must be done in the machine where the web applicaiton is launched(client machine). Is there any simple way to do it. I am using C# .net 4.0, javascript. Thanks

Comment: Stream the file itself or convert it to PDF and stream that.

Comment: how to print the streamed excel file ?

Answer (score 0):

you may consider using 3rd party products as :

1. Aspose Cells 
   http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.cells-product-family/default.aspx
   you can convert EXCEL file to HTML and then print it on client machine just regular html .
2. Telerik 
   http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[TMS TMS Flexcel Studio for .NET](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) can convert the XLS file to a PDF. Stream the PDF back to the web client. It is **very** reasonably priced, without any server royalties.